# Teminal Services Manager or RDS - managing user access to specific applications

Tags: windows-terminal-services, remote-desktop-services

I have a project that I am purposing my company go to a TS or RDS system rather than a tradition desktop environment.  The issue that I've been asked to research is if we can restrict a certain amount of users to access an application at one time.  I.e. if I go into a photoshop application can I make it so no one else can use that application even if this app is available in the users group?

Answer (score 1):

You can install the application to a remote folder that is a network share, and specify a connection limit on the share.  Of course the application would need to tested to ensure it works properly when run from a network share by concurrent users.

Comment: `There is no built-in tool to limit concurrent usage of specific RemoteApps.  To accomplish this you will need to write your own program or use a third-party software such as AppSense Application Manager that is designed to enforce concurrent licensing.`  @  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/zh/winserverTS/thread/5da858ca-e435-4bbd-8cef-8e7cea995475

Answer (score 0):

If you are still on the proposal stage then I assume you haven't decided yet which technology you are going to use so I've checked the Citrix Delivery Services Console for you and I found an option which lets you limit the number of instances per application if that's what you were looking for.
If you're in the console expand Citrix Resources -> Xenapp -> FarmName -> Applications -> right click on an application and choose Properties.

[image: Application Properties]